# Trying to parse a diffGram created by the XMLDiffAndPatch

Tags: xml, diff, patch

I'm using the 'XML Diff and Patch' dll in order to compare two XML's.
Is there any simple way to parse the DiffGram into data that could be easily comprehended to the user?
For example, I need this DiffGram:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="2079810781567709607" 
options="IgnoreChildOrder IgnoreNamespaces IgnorePrefixes" 
xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
   <xd:node match="1">
      <xd:add type="1" name="Subaru" ns="http://www.Subaru.com" prefix="ns2">
         <xd:add type="2" name="model">Impreza</xd:add> 
            <xd:add>
               <ns2:Muffler xmlns:ns2="http://www.Subaru.com">450</ns2:Muffler> 
               <ns2:Bumper xmlns:ns2="http://www.Subaru.com">120</ns2:Bumper> 
               <ns2:Floormat xmlns:ns2="http://www.Subaru.com">65</ns2:Floormat> 
            </xd:add>
         <xd:add match="/1/2/4" opid="1" /> 
      </xd:add>
      <xd:node match="2">
         <xd:node match="1">
            <xd:change match="1">600</xd:change> 
         </xd:node>
         <xd:add>
            <ns2:WindShieldWipers xmlns:ns2="http://www.Subaru.com">25</ns2:WindShieldWipers>
         </xd:add>
         <xd:remove match="4" opid="1" /> 
      </xd:node>
   </xd:node>
   <xd:descriptor opid="1" type="move" /> 
</xd:xmldiff>
```

To be translated into easy to understand steps for the user to follow. (for example: add 'Value' in Path: 1->12->25)

Thanks, Hadar

Answer (score 0):

use xmldiffpatch view class or use [xmlnotepad](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7973) for the html comparison.